# How to stock what's after a str.startsWith into a variable in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, numbers, dice, startswith

Well guys, I'm having a little issue here. Me and some pals are working in a Twitch bot using Tmi.JS, and we've been wondering how to make a dice that can be of 2 or infinitum faces.

A friend said that we could make it by using the .startsWith function, but when we try that, we just get the `!dx` (command to call the Infinitum Dice) logged into the console, and not what's after it.

I've worked with `process.stdout.write(commandName);` to see the value of commandName (that in this case is `!dxNumber`. We tried this two ways of getting the numbers after !dx:

```
case message.startsWith("!dx"):
case message.startsWith("!dx", 3):
```

In the first case, as you may be wondering, we just get !dx, but in the second one we dont get nothing. And I know why is that, and it's because the 3 is pointing at three letters past the initial doble-quote, and obviously, there's nothing there. So. Is there a way to get just the a number using startsWith or other function?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use substring to stock them like

```js
var a = "hello-world"

if (a.startsWith("hello")) console.log(a.substring("hello".length))
```

Comment: I want to stock what's after the `!dx`, not the `!dx` itself. :(